# How to get previous URL of the tab whose URL is changed (using Chrome API)

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am opening extension frame when tab loads completely or URL is changed:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, currentTab) => {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete' || changeInfo.url) {
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, () => {
      openFrameIfSuccess(tabId, currentTab)
    })
  }
})
```

But I also don't want multiple extension frame to be opened in a single tab.
So I am storing unique hashes of tabId and url of that tab in which extension is enabled(storing it in cookies, so that it can be persistent).

Now I also want to remove those hashes when Url changes or new tab is opened.

I can track when URL is changed using Chrome API, but how can I get the previous URL of that tab, whose URL is changed using Chrome API ?

Comment: There's no such API.